# Proxy only return target through get method when trying to return a different value

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-proxy

I am trying to just give the user the string "Hello" everytime the proxy is called through the get method. Instead, I am getting an empty object, which is my target.

I've tried to use classes like String, Reflect with no positive results

```
let proxy = new Proxy({},{
    get: function ()
    {
         return "Hello"
    }
})


console.log(proxy)
```

Expected: "Hello"
Result: {}

Answer (score 2):

> every time the proxy is called through the get method.

That's not what the `get` trap is made for. The method will handle *property accesses*, not accesses of the proxy itself. Your (proxy) object doesn't have any properties, they are not accessed, so all you see is the empty object.

See the `get` trap in action here:

```js
const proxy = new Proxy({},{
    get: function () {
         return "Hello"
    }
})
console.log(proxy.someProperty, proxy.really, proxy.anything)
console.log(proxy)
```

> I am trying to just give the user the string "Hello"

That's not possible. A proxy is always an object. It cannot masquerade as a primitive string.

Comment: Thank that is very helpful

Answer (score 1):

Possible if you covert it to string

```
let proxy = new Proxy({},{
    get: function ()
    {
         return () => "Hello" // Proxy Symbol.toPrimitive
    }
})
console.log(String(proxy), proxy == 'Hello')
```